# Downloading ROI Explorer plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm following a tutorial about classifying pixels colours into categories and need to download the ROI Explorer plugin. Can't seem to find it anywhere however.

Does anyone know how I can get it or if there's an alternative?

My plan is to classify certain colours in satellite imagery so as to get an idea of % forest cover.

Comment: Try here: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/roitool/version/0.1.1/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `Semi Automatic Classification Plugin`: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/

It is a very good tool to do classifications of satellite imagery. Used it myself a lot and it is quite easy to handle. Also there are lots of tutorials available.

However, here is the link to ROIExplorer: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/roitool/ It seems to be pretty outdatet though, as the last update was in 2015. So chances are low it gets updated for QGIS3.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS 3 represented a major overhaul of the program, and all plugins became obsolete when 3.0 was released. If you must use a plugin that hasn't been updated for QGIS 3, run an older version of QGIS. The previous long-term release version (2.18) is still available on the main [downloads page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html). Older versions are available [here](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/).